# Unable to open Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I am unable to open my Atom Editor. It was working fine until yesterday, but don't know why it won't open today. No windows update or anything on my computer. I tried deleting the 'Storage' folder as mentioned in some online forums, doesn't help. Any suggestions? I am using Atom version 1.19.6.0.

Comment: I have never had this problem with Atom specifically, but with other software on Windows 10 I have occasionally noticed that issues with a program failing to launched can be solved by finding all instances of that program in Task Manager and ending them. What OS are you using? Have you done a clean install of Atom? Good luck..

Comment: Thanks, Michael. The OS is Windows 10. What is a "clean install"? I am sorry, I am not a programmer full time.

Comment: it means to uninstall and reinstall Atom

Comment: I haven't done that. Let me try uninstall and reinstall. Thanks.

Comment: I reinstalled, and it seems to be working fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 34):

If you're using MAC OS and have similar problem, try this:
Open Window tab

[image: window tab]

and then click Zoom.

[image: Zoom]

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question was asked 3 years ago, and the OS in question is Windows 10.

Comment: Sure, you are right, but I had same problem on Mac OS and it was quite hard to find the right answer. As I did not see similar solution as mine I wanted to share it for someone who will have similar problem in future.

Comment: Your answer is appreciated. There is also a Q&A format to help share knowledge with community. You can ask a question and answer it yourself (linking to this question for Windows).

Answer (score 18):

Atom will sometime fail to open because of a bad configuration-file.

To better diagnose this on Windows (10), try running atom from a CMD window:

1. Open the task-manager and kill any instance of *Atom* that is listed there
2. Open a *Command-window* -
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> > (type "command") > <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Go to where *Atom* is installed -
   `cd %USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/atom/app-*`
4. Run *Atom* -
   `atom.exe`

If you see an error message at this point, it should help identify the problem.

If still not clear, you can try moving the main configuration-file,
which is in a different folder:

1. `cd %USERPROFILE%/.atom/`
2. `rename config.cson config.SAVE.cson`
3. Go to where *Atom* is installed (again) -
   `cd %USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/atom/app-*`
4. Run *Atom* -
   `atom.exe`

Based on this answer on the Atom forum:
https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-will-not-open-windows/47489

Comment: You saved me after a few hours of searching and reinstalling without effect. Thanks!

Comment: Saved my day! Atom wasn't opening due to an incorrect `config.cson` file

Comment: you save my life

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this issue when my Atom windows all suddenly resized to be so small I could not see or find them anywhere (some weird glitch with opening it from a full-screen window on an external display). I resolved it by command-tabbing (I think it's ctrl-tab on Windows, I forget) to my open atom application to bring up the application's menu bar, and then selecting `Window` > `Zoom` from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Atom on Windows 10 64-bit, and had similar problems of installation and not running later.

You can do the following:

1. Empty Trash, and Temp and Prefetch folders.
2. Change the security and read only properties of the temp folder.
3. IMP > Disable antivirus and run atom it will work, later add the Atom app to exclusion list of your antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the task-manager and kill any instance of Atom that is listed there
2. Got to where Atom installed : Mine:> C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\atom

[See this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8cqi.jpg)

Go to Folder indicated in the picture and find atom.exe by scrolling through the folder and open it and make a shortcut to desktop and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that mv command is not builtin Windows cmd as suggested by Gonen. So following the idea of Gonen, a working solution can also be like:

1. In windows explorer type %USERPROFILE%/.atom/, or manually go to the path
   (in my case): C:\Users\hussainazhar.atom. Of course, go to your drive path accordingly. Close Atom application if already opened.
2. Simply rename the config.cson to config.SAVE.cson
3. Open up the Atom and now you can go to the settings :)

Comment: Silly me - was using the Unix command (`mv`) instead of Windows (`rename`)... fixing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you simply need to do is go the main directly where the file is located and open the FIRST folder.

After opening it, there you will see atom file, double click on it and it will be opened successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The atom Window is just minimized, it gives the impression of not openning, but it is actually opening, again is just minimized.

I was able to see the atom interface, by maximizing the window using the keyboard:
on windows, it normally is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SpaceBar</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.