# Can't open atom in windows 10 after installing

Tags: atom-editor

I have installed atom in windows 10 but can't open it.

I've tried to open from cmd but it didn't work.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: this is odd, maybe something went wrong with the installation, have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: @RamaSalahat yes I did

Comment: check this ticket out, it could be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099224/unable-to-open-atom?rq=1#:~:text=Atom%20will%20sometime%20fail%20to,of%20a%20bad%20configuration%2Dfile.&text=If%20you%20see%20an%20error,should%20help%20identify%20the%20problem.